# Serializing Generic KeyValue item issue in Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I have this class structure:

```
public class GraphDataItem<TCategory, TValue>
{
    public TCategory Category { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public GraphDataItem(TCategory category, TValue value)
    {
        Category = category;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I have a collection of this items, that I serialize using something like this:

```
List<GraphDataItem<DateTime, int>> items = GetItems();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

The json output that I get looks like this:

```
[{"Category":"2014-04-30T00:00:00","Value":1},
 {"Category":"2014-05-01T00:00:00","Value":38},
 {"Category":"2014-05-02T00:00:00","Value":18}]
```

I want the default DateTime serializing behaviour, that will produce something like:

```
[{"Category":/Date(1245398693390)/,"Value":1},
 {"Category":/Date(1245398693390)/,"Value":38},
 {"Category":/Date(1245398693390)/,"Value":18}]
```

I suspect that the library is calling Category's `toString()` instead of the standard method. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `DateFormatHandling` and `DateTimeZoneHandling` settings when you serialize, e.g.:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;

List<GraphDataItem<DateTime, int>> items = GetItems();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

The default date serialization format used by JSON.Net is Microsoft date format. So you should be getting dates like you want. Ensure that while serializing, you're not using `IsoDateTimeConverter`.

This [post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net) about different date serialization options might be helpful.

Also, if you're using latest JSON.Net, you can use [serialization tracing](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/11/20/json-net-4-5-release-11-serialization-tracing) to see what's going on inside. That may turn up helpful clues as to why this is happening or how you can force it to produce correct output.

If everything else fails, you may have to resort to your a custom JsonConverter:

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ...
        if(value is DateTime) {
            var d = value as DateTime;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, d);
        } 
        else {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

        ...
    }

    // other overrides
}
```

Comment: *The default date serialization format used by JSON.Net is Microsoft date format*.  This is no longer true.  The default is ISO date format; it has been this way since version 4.5 release 1.  See release notes [here](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/84550).

Comment: Ahh, that explains. So in that case, your answer should take care of it.